# Cannot access to parent model from child view

Tags: ember.js, model, handlebars.js

I have a problem with my emberjs view. I cannot access to the model defined in the parent view. I have tested with view.parentView.model and this not working

Here is my code :

```
<div class="allowed_name">{{model.allowed_email_domain}}</div><!-- working -->
{{#each view.content}}
  <h1>{{model.allowed_email_domain}}</h1> <!-- not working -->
{{/each}}
```

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that you are using the view and probably shouldn't be, it's because you've changed the context inside the each loop.

Depending on the version of handlebars/htmlbars you are using

```
<div class="allowed_name">{{model.allowed_email_domain}}</div><!-- working -->
{{#each view.content as |item|}}
  <h1>{{model.allowed_email_domain}}</h1> <!-- working -->
{{/each}}


<div class="allowed_name">{{model.allowed_email_domain}}</div><!-- working -->
{{#each item in view.content}}
  <h1>{{model.allowed_email_domain}}</h1> <!-- working -->
{{/each}}
```